# Share macros modules between excel and word

Tags: vba, excel, macros, ms-word

Over the last two years I have written several macros for excel and word and saving them in normal.dotm and personal.xlsm. I have some modules that handles filereading,database interactions, html parsing and so on, these modules are exact the same both in word and excel. Untill now I have just copied them between those two applications. Is it possible to somehow have them stored in one locations(as a library) and then use them in both applications?

I guess it could be possible to write a module that export it to a given location and then deletes them for so import them again to make sure that I remember to copy all modules between those two, but this seems like the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Store the common functions in a vbs file and load them from macros. Of course you may require to revisit the functions to make sure they do not have excel or word specific code.

Comment: I have been reading through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript, however I am unsure how I load an vbs file into my personal.xlsm or normal.dotm file, say I  create filehandling.vbs which has the function fileexist which return true or false, how can I then use this in my vba module? `msgbox filehandling.vbs!fileexist("c:\test.txt")` which then can be used both in word and excel

Comment: On vacation so I cannot invest much time on this for now or give you code samples. Try searching on internet for cscript.exe and vbs file.

Comment: Thanks, however it seems like with cscript I can run my macro, but It can not return objects. I might be wrong though. So i can check if the fileexist but it can not return true or false to me, or the object of the file.

Comment: @skatun, were you able to proceed or the problem resolved ?

Comment: not so far. I can figure out how to call vbs routines stored on network drive from a module inside excel or word

Comment: gr8. Now the problem is with the logic rather than vbs file function calling.

Comment: OOps, a critical typo, should say cant... and not can, So I am still in the blind how to be able to call the modules from within excel or word